# are there ways to improve inference results on a pretrained machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection

I am trying to get inference from a pre-trained machine learning object detection model(detr) on to jrdb dataset(https://jrdb.stanford.edu/). I am using the demo code provided by the team that authored the paper. Here is the link to the code: [detr_demo](https://colab.research.google.com/github/facebookresearch/detr/blob/colab/notebooks/detr_demo.ipynb)

I have changed the model to resnet-101 and the weights file to the best they have reported on the GitHub repo(https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr) for the code. yet, the Average precision score I am getting on the jrdb test dataset is 15.8 AP. while, the best result on the same code using the pre-trained model and weights for another team is 48 AP, as reported on the jrdb leaderboard for 2d detection(https://jrdb.stanford.edu/leaderboards/results/412). What I wish to know is, are there ways to improve inference, without retraining? I have searched on google and most links show to better train the model.

Comment: I imagine they would have fine-tuned the transformer part on the jrdb dataset.

Comment: how exactly? which parts can i finetune which would be considered as not retraining?

Comment: I don't know whether there's an answer that works in all cases but you can try just finetuning the feed-forward layers that predict boxes and classes (i.e. load and freeze the pretrained COCO weights for the CNN and transformer).

Comment: since I am just inferring and not training, wouldn't freezing weights make no difference?

Comment: If the model wasn't trained on that data, then you can expect it's performance to be as good as it is on data similar to what it was trained on. So if you just use those weights unchanged the performance won't improve. That's why finetuning can be useful since you don't have to retrain the whole model.

Comment: I'm not sure why the authors didn't describe how they used the JRDB data.